# How do I do transparent vendor mixins in Stylus when the mixin function is an argument?

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

Making a mixin for properties like `border-radius` is easy:

```
vendor(name, args)
    -webkit-{name} args
    -moz-{name} args
    -ie-{name} args
    -o-{name} args
    {name} args

border-radius()
    vendor('border-radius', arguments)

#test
    border-radius 5px
```

But what if I want to create a transparent vendor mixin for `linear-gradient`? Unlike `border-radius`, `linear-gradient` is not a property but an argument, e.g.

```
#test
    background-image linear-gradient(top, #f00 0%, #00f 100%)
```

I'm thinking I have to create a mixin called `background-image` and check if the first argument is `linear-gradient`. Is Stylus capable of such advanced logic? If so, how can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for any help on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the nib project? http://visionmedia.github.com/nib/ It has all of the mixins you would want for stylus. Even if you don't end up using nib, you can still look at their code (https://github.com/visionmedia/nib/blob/master/lib/nib/gradients.styl#L106 for linear-gradient)

Comment: That's pretty much a perfect solution. I just copy-pasted the *lib/nib* folder into my Stylus directory and added `@import 'nib'`, and now everything works perfectly. Thanks!